# Dates do not coexist in DAX POWER BI

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, measure

I have a measure in dax (# cancellations) that occupies the "unsubscription date" field, I made one more measure that occupies (# cancellations) however this measure is taken using the month of another field, my measures do not coexist due to the dates For example, if I want to see my headcount measurement for the month of October, it will not be the same number of cancellations as if I view the cancellations with a cancellation date of October. Any suggestions on how I can make the dates coexist?

I want to see my losses and my headcount together.I attach my measures as an example and the result I obtain when putting them together.

```
bajas totales = 

CALCULATE(
    COUNTAX(
        VALUES(base[Numero de Empleado]),
        base[Numero de Empleado]
    ),base[TABLA] = "ACTUAL" && base[Estatus en Nómina] ="BAJA") +0



headcount_rotacion_mesant = CALCULATE(
SUM(base[Column]),
KEEPFILTERS(
    base[Estatus en Nómina] = "ACTIVO" &&
    base[Column 2_ historico] = 1 &&
    not ISBLANK(base[AREA]) ))
```

If I saw October data

```
num_mes  headcount_rotacion_mesant bajas totales   fecha baja
  10              (blank)              10          11/10/2023
  11              (blank)              9           05/10/2023
  12              (blank)              2           01/10/2023

num_mes  headcount_rotacion_mesant
  10            1414
  11            1547
```

Comment: Please update your question with more details on your data model (like which date fields) and also share the measure for "this measure is taken using the month of another field". Need to see which ever measure is referencing the date field(s).